# I am getting Encoding Error when i try to creat mail pdf

Tags: node.js, buffer

I am using NodeJS 8.11.1 and npm libraries and when i set all right for template.render() i get buffer encoding error. Also when i set the right path for templates.render('meatball-sandwich.html', context, function(err, html, text, subject) i am getting html as undefined.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var EmailTemplates = require('swig-email-templates');
var options = {format: 'A4'}; // allowed units: A3, A4, A5, Legal, Letter, Tabloid
```

and i am Getting this error

```
buffer.js:597
  throw new TypeError('Unknown encoding: ' + encoding);
  ^

TypeError: Unknown encoding: 
    at stringSlice (buffer.js:597:9)
    at Buffer.toString (buffer.js:633:10)
```

Fixed by updating swig-email-templates to latest version

Comment: Can you share the code where you are using pdf

Comment: pdf.create(html,options).toBuffer(function (err, buffer) {
   console.log('This is a buffer:', Buffer.isBuffer(buffer));
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error on pdf :"+err);
        } else {.....

Comment: if i use 
html = fs.readFileSync('my html template path', 'utf8');
i am getting throught toBuffer();
but 
 templates.render('html path' context , function() )
is not reading my context and cant pass values to template